# Script for dynamic pages in Load Runner

Tags: loadrunner, stress-testing

There is a resource http://test.youplace.net

We need to write a script for the Load Runner that emulates the passage of the test using this link with the conditions: "test" is entered in the inputtext, the longest value is selected in the radio or lists.

The problem is that the pages are dynamically generated by the server, i.e.  the number of text fields, radio buttons and lists is constantly filled with different numbers.  The total number of questions (pages) in the test is also not static.

Which side to approach the script for this beast?

So far I have just started working on LoadRunner.  I don’t know where to start this task.

Comment: Also, this is a site that people are sent to as a check against their sills prior to employment.   You should complete it, not the community.  It is not a test of the community skills.

Comment: Complete the self paced training and the answer will be obvious

Comment: I would start with TruWeb or TruClient protocol.